# Probability that Array of Numbers Came from Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to figure out how compute the probability that an *array* of values came from a given distribution. For example, I want to determine that  probability that `[0.9, 0.3, 0.7]` came from a Uniform distribution. I know that the probability of getting any *specific* value from a continuous distribution is **zero**. However, some arrays of numbers are far more uniform-like in their distribution than others.

One way I have thought about the problem is Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) of the array from the mean of the distribution. For example, I wrote a little MATLAB script to estimate the RMSE Probability Distribution Function for an array of uniform numbers.

[image]

An array like `[0.9, 0.3, 0.7]` has an RMSE of `0.28` which is entirely reasonable whereas `[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]` has an RMSE of zero, which is almost impossible given this PDF. However, this approach isn't right either. An array like `[0.8, 0.8, 0.8]` is just as unlike a uniform distribution as `[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]` and yet it's RMSE is 0.3 which is reasonable. I think there must be an algorithm to do this, I suspect that I just don't know the right key-words for searching. I'm an engineer, not a probability and stats guy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [goodness-of-fit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit#Fit_of_distributions).

There you find an often used test called the [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test).
But you will find there also other fitting tests.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was looking for! Unfortunately, the data for my real-world problem that I'm working on does not have Independent Identically Distributed error. But this has still been very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. :-)